# Detect which line of JS is manipulating a given HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-devtools

I was just coding my site **[HERE](http://purplefront.net/opulent_gallery_bug/)**

> username: purplefront
>
> password: purple123

Now the problem is in the gallery, go to the gallery section and click on any of the images and you'll see that after the popup appears and closes, the image on the thumbnail disspears , if you check the inspect element , there is some JS that is obviously manipulating the `display` property.

I did a small hack that is set the `display:block !important` .

Is there anyway to zero down and identify which line of JS is doing the manipulation?

P.S. I use chrome for debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an inline style is technically a DOM-tree modification you can just right-click the element in the 'Elements' tab, select 'Break on...' at the bottom, and then 'Attribute Modifications'. It will then pause in the JS debugger with a full callstack to zero in on the location.